# Regular expression to allow some characters and text symbols

Tags: regex

I've made a regex to validate my form and guarantee that only some characters are allowed. For 'normal characters' as abcde... it works but i can't make it work with text symbols like ✈ or ❤.

Here is what i use to allow characters:

```
^[\x00-\x21\x23-\x26\x28-\x3a\x3d\x3f-\xff\xa8\xE2\x9C\x88]
```

And for allow text symbols, i've tried it:

```
^[\x00-\x21\x23-\x26\x28-\x3a\x3d\x3f-\xff\xa8\xE2\x9C\x88\x2708\x2764]
```

I've checked this website https://www.branah.com/ascii-converter to get hex codes and i saw that text symbols are a mix of "something" and characters like <> ' " (these aren't allowed in my regex).

Any idea how i could make it work and not allow characters like <>'"?

Thank in advance.

Comment: What regex engine are you using?

Comment: "Here is what i use to *allow* characters". More like *disallow* due to the negation

Comment: @BrianStephens RegularExpression from C#

Comment: @blueygh2 that's a start of string anchor, not a negation, since it's out of the character class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that in C# regex, you want to use `\u` as the unicode hex escape prefix (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). So try something like this:

`[\u2708\u2764]`

to match ✈ or ❤. It's equivalent to

`[\x{2708}\x{2764}]`

in some other languages.